Greasemonkey: change text in HTML
I have looked at several solutions for similar problems in here but I wasn't able to understand either
The webpage I'm trying to edit has the following bit:
<h4 data-v-42b52bab="" class="title is-4 mt-4">Behemoth <!----></h4>
I'm trying to make it say "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51" instead of Behemoth
What I attempted was:
var strongElems = document.getElementsByClassName('is-4');

for (var i=0; i<strongElems.length; i++)
{
  var thisElem = strongElems[i];
   thisElem.textContent = "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51"; // change it
}

But it doesn't seem to work. What can I do?
Edit:
I tried with a setTimeout and thisElem.innerHTML to no success
var strongElems = document.getElementsByClassName('is-4');


setTimeout(function() {


for (var i=0; i<strongElems.length; i++)
{
  var thisElem = strongElems[i];
   thisElem.innerHTML = "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51";
}
  
}, 5000); 

}); 

The full code of the page can't be added as it goes beyond the character limit. The URL of the page I want to edit is https://zhu.codes/paissa?world=78&sizes=0
Second edit:
The answer with InnerText alongside a correction on setTimeout worked
var strongElems = document.getElementsByClassName('is-4');
console.log(strongElems.length);

setTimeout(function() {

for (let i = 0; i < strongElems.length; i++) {
  let thisElem = strongElems[i];
  thisElem.innerText = "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51";
}
  
}, 3000); 



Your target element(s) might be dynamically inserted, so you can try to delay execution for a few seconds.

I added a setTimeout with 5000 miliseconds just to be sure, but didn't work either

you can use innerHTML.
example thisElem. innerHTML = "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51"

The problem is not reproducible (that code does exactly what you want). Please includes more details that help reproduce the problem. Otherwise, we can't say anything more that "it works", and start to do random guess about why it may not work in your case. Also, the "delay" hypothesis is a very plausible one ; and your timeout is way to avoid that problem (at least to rule out that it is the problem). But then you need to show us that setTimeout also)

I edited the post with more context for reproducibility

You are using wrong property to write that selected test.  Instead of textContent you're supposed to use innerText.


var strongElems = document.getElementsByClassName('is-4');
console.log(strongElems.length);

for (let i = 0; i < strongElems.length; i++) {
  let thisElem = strongElems[i];
  thisElem.innerText = "Plots 19, 20, 21, 49, 50, 51"; // change it
}
<h4 data-v-42b52bab="" class="title is-4 mt-4">Select a World</h4>
<h4 data-v-42b52bab="" class="title is-4 mt-4">
  Behemoth
  <!---->
</h4>




Thanks, using innerText and a minor fix on the SetTimeout worked!
